# Rational points on quadratic curves

Tags: polynomials

I guess this question might be very difficult, so I would only like to know what is known about it.

Given a *quadratic* polynomial $P$ in two variables with degree $2$ and integer coefficients. Assume $P = 0$ has real solutions. Does this imply that there are also rational solutions to it?
I am really only interested in quadratic polynomials. 
In case the answer is yes: are the rational solutions dense?
In case of no: Is it a 'common' or 'rare' event to have a polynom without rational solutions?

thanks
Till

Answer (score 7):

The quadratic equation $x^2+y^2-3=0$ has real but no rational solutions.

If a non-singular conic $C$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a rational point $P$
then all rational points on $P$ can be parameterised. Let $t\in\mathbb{Q}$ and let $L_t$ be the line through $P$ with slope $t$. Then $L_t$ meets $C$ in two points: $P$ and $Q_t$. Then $t\mapsto Q_t$ is a parameterisation
of the rational points on $C$. (OK you need to also consider the "$t=\infty$" case).

From the parameterisation, it is easily seen that the rational points
are dense within the real points.

As a classic example, let $C$ be the unit circle $x^2+y^2-1$ and $P$ the point $(1,0)$. The line $L_t$ has equation $y=t(x-1)$ which meets $C$ in $P$ and $Q_t=((t^2-1)/(1+t^2),-2t/(1+t^2))$. As $t$ varies over $\Bbb Q$
we all the rational points on the unit circle. To see they are dense in the real points, a typical real point is also $Q_t$ but with $t\in\Bbb R$. Just take a sequence of rationals converging to $t$.